# Laravel MIME issue while validating .csv file

Tags: validation, laravel-5, mime

I have read couple of post regarding the issue of checking the file extension while upload a file using laravel.

I have the same issue and didn't file the solution even if spending an hour behinding the silly thing.

this is my validation rule looks like.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
       'sheet' => 'required',
       'file' => 'mimes:csv',
    ];
}
```

However required is working file but on mimes.

I tried couple of other ways i founded like:

```php
return [
    'sheet' => ['required', 'mimes:csv']
]
```

```php
return [
    'sheet' => ['required', 'mimes:text/csv']
]
```

```php
return [
    'sheet' => 'required|mimes:text/csv'
];
```

```php
return [
    'sheet' => 'required|mimes:csv'
];
```

```php
return [
    'sheet'          => 'required',
    'extension'      => 'required|in:csv'
];
```

Above none of line is working sometime says not valid file sometime passes through the validation.

I doubted for invalid file, then I downloaded fresh sample file from Microsoft site. That not the issue at all.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: **application/csv**.

Comment: No luck! I posted answer. That is working for me!

Answer (score 35):

Surprised!

Its getting `text/plain` mime for the CSV, that was the cause of the issue.

So to fix this I just found which extension is responsible for `text/plain` and I found **txt** so i just updated my rules:

```php
return [
    'sheet' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt'
];
```

Comment: I add an .sql file and apply your validate rule but its still pass.

Comment: But why this is happening, when I dumped the file variable it shows `mimeType: "text/csv"`

Comment: This answer is not correct. Because user can upload txt files too!

Comment: CSV is in fact text. Only a different extension.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue, and even if it was old, I wish that this will help the others.
To fix this, you have to know what mime you got from your request, to find it use this line of code:

```
dd($request->file('document')->getMimeType(),$request->file('document')->getClientOriginalExtension() );
```

So in my case, the file that I uploaded was CSV but I got a txt file extension. So I solved it like the previous answers in this post by just adding txt to request validation:

```
return [
    'sheet' => "required|mimes:csv,txt",
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are several types I used for more complete **csv validation**, hope it will help future usage

```
        return [
            'sheet' => 'required|mimetypes:text/csv,text/plain,application/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/anytext,application/octet-stream,application/txt'
        ];
```