# Laravel import csv file failed

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to implement an import csv file on my web. When I tried to import the csv file, the csv file is not saving into the database, and when I tried to `dd()` it, it shows no errors, and not showing the result of the `dd()`, but the import failed. How to resolve this issue?

The model :

```
<?php

namespace Modules\User\Imports;

use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class VendorImport implements  ToModel, WithCalculatedFormulas
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        
        // Implement your import logic here
        //dd($row);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $row[0],
            'first_name' => $row[1],
            'last_name' => $row[2],
            'email'=> $row[3],
            'email_verified_at'=> Carbon::now()->timestamp,
            'password'=> $row[5],
            'address'=> $row[6],
            'address2'=> $row[7],
            'phone'=> $row[8],
            'phone2'=> $row[9],
            'birthday'=> $row[10],
            'city'=> $row[11],
            'state'=> $row[12],
            'country'=> $row[13],
            'zip_code'=> $row[14],
            'last_login_at'=> $row[15],
            'avatar_id'=> $row[16],
            'bio'=> $row[17],
            'status'=> $row[18],
            'create_user'=> $row[19],
            'update_user'=> $row[20],
            'vendor_commission_amount'=> $row[21],
            'vendor_commission_type'=> $row[22],
            'deleted_at'=> null,
            'remember_token'=> $row[24],
            'created_at'=> Carbon::now()->timestamp,
            'updated_at'=> Carbon::now()->timestamp,
            'payment_gateway'=> $row[27],
            'total_guests'=> $row[28],
            'locale'=> $row[29],
            'business_name'=> $row[30],
            'avatar'=> $row[31],
            'messenger_color'=> $row[32],
            'dark_mode'=> $row[33],
            'active_status'=> $row[34],
            'verify_submit_status'=> $row[35],
            'is_verified'=> $row[36],
            'user_name'=> $row[37],
            'member'=> $row[38],
            'role'=> $row[39],
        ]);
        
        $user->save(); // Corrected method call

        if ($role = Role::findById(1)) {
            $user->syncRoles([$role]);
        }
        return $user;
    }
    
    // public function sheets(): array
    // {
    //     return [
    //         'users' => new UserImportSheet(),
    //     ];
    // }
}
```

The controller :

```
public function import(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv'
        ]);
    
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = rand() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('file_vendor', $nama_file);
    
        Excel::import(new VendorImport, public_path('/file_vendor/' . $nama_file));
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', __('Upload successfully!'));
    }
```

The route :

```
Route::get('/import', 'UserController@import_form')->name('user.admin.import.form');
Route::post('/import', 'UserController@import')->name('user.admin.import');
```

The view :

```
<form action="{{ route('user.admin.import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Upload Excel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: check if file is storing properly, and also check file path, it is retrieving correctly.

Comment: When you use dd($row) in vendor import class, what are you getting ?

Comment: When i use dd($row) i got nothing, it's not showing me the result of array

Answer (score 1):

I have debug and looks like execution stops in import method at UserController.

```
public function import(Request $request)
{        
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv'
        ]);
}
```

You execution is not processing after validate csv file please try to remove mimes:csv from the validating because of csv return always txt mime.

One more thing please use public_path() instead of absolute path I have changed code i.e. $file->move(public_path()."/file_vendor/", $nama_file); and check in directory is there csv file uploading successfully or not if yes then you can check in dd(). Please check attached image.

[image]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't reach the `dd()` it probably get stuck at validation (status code 422).

Try to change the validation to `'required|mimes:csv,txt'` (will accept txt-files) or just try to remove `mimes` validation to identify the issue. If this would be the solution, you could try to also validate the file extension to avoid `.txt` uploads (probably requires custom validation rule).

> Even though you only need to specify the extensions when invoking the types method, this method actually validates the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type.
> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-files-file-types

More about CSV-validation issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585014/22367649